# What is the name of this laptop port?

Tags: laptop, port, connector

Laptop is Acer TravelMate 331T.

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a "guessing-game" type question.  See http://meta.superuser.com/a/6074/23133

Answer (score 10):

It is the "Easy Link" Combo Drive port.

From the service manual  "The EasyLink™ Combo Drive is a two-in-one floppy/CD-ROM or floppy /DVD-ROM “combo” drive that connects externally to the computer"  Picture of drive is here: [Acer EasyLink Drive](http://www.oninocomputing.co.uk/dvd_drives/acer_easylink_dvd_combo_91_45s37_002)

Good manual here [Acer Service Manual](http://www.elhvb.com/mobokive/edwin/laptops/Acer/TM330SG.PDF)