# What is this port/connector on my laptop?

Tags: port, connector

I have this port on my laptop and I have no idea what is it used for. It's not even listen in the laptop technical specifications. The laptop is a HP Pavillion dv5-1101en.

[image: Unknown computer port]

Here is a larger image showing all the ports on the laptop:

[image: Unknown computer port close-up]

Left to right:

1. D-sub 15 pin (AKA VGA)
2. Unknown port
3. Ethernet
4. HDMI
5. eSATA
6. USB
7. IEEE 1394 (AKA FireWire)

Comment: Can't post two links or even images because I need 1 more rep. Sigh...

Comment: check http://superuser.com/questions/110955/what-is-the-name-of-this-laptop-port .. it doesn't quite look like the same thing to me, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: @quack, it doesn't seem to be the same thing - this one is smaller and the pins are tightly grouped. Laptop isn't an Acer either.

Comment: This is the typical "A port you won't ever use" port. :-D

Comment: @Shiki, I have to agree with you!

Comment: (Sorry the manual is too long. check m0jo's answer oO) (By the way docking on the side? What the heck? oO)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a "guessing-game" type question. See meta.superuser.com/a/6074/23133

Comment: @techie007, well I don't think that was the policy back in 2010. Wouldn't do much good to close it now when it's been inactive for a reaaaally long time, would it?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/709913/how-do-i-identify-hardware-i-am-unfamiliar-with-on-my-computer?lq=1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a docking connector for the HP XB4 docking station and other expansion devices.

[image]

.

Found in your Service manual [at this page](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-pavilion-dv5-1100-entertainment-notebook-pc-series/3744201/model/3826166/manuals)

Comment: Right! I totally forgot about the docking station. Still fits Shiki's "A port you won't ever use" port though.

Comment: What is the data throughput for a docking connector port like this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a dock connector to me

Answer (score 0):

Mini [SCSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCSI) port maybe?

Comment: It does look like that (and that was my first thought), though I can't see the point of SCSI on an "entertainment" laptop. Counting pins is impractical - they're too many and way to small :(

Comment: http://www.ramelectronics.net/scsi_connectors.ep ... does look a bit like the HD50/HD68 connectors.  again, hard to tell.  a clearer pic would help.

Comment: @quack, unfortunately I took this using my mobile phone, I gave my digital camera to a friend a few days ago. I'll update the pics when I get the camera back.